# laravel 5.2 only paginate data with current user id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to paginate the data according to current logged in user.

this is my controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $dosen = Dosen::paginate(5);
    return view('dosen.index', compact('dosen'));
}
```

Comment: It depends on what data is associated to the currently logged in user. That is, you have consider about the relationships between entities

Comment: You should add some rules over `Dosen` to return items related to current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you've a `user_id` column in your `Dosen` model table. So you can say

```
$dosen = Dosen::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->paginate(5);

return view('dosen.index', compact('dosen'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get current login user by `Auth::user()->id`

So pass it in your query.

```
$dosen = Dosen::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->paginate(5);
```

**Note**:- `user_id` is your dosen table column name.

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter the result using query and then apply paginate on the result to get the result-set of logged in user only.

**Like this,**

```
$doesn_query = Dosen::query();
$doesn_query->where('user','=',$userid); // Replace $userid with logged in user id.
$result = $doesn_query->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Undefined variable: user_id

Comment: Replace `$userid` with the ID of your logged in user.